# What is the derivative of matrix vector product $(A^Tx)$ with respect to A?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

What is the derivative of a vector with respect to a matrix? 
Specifically, $\frac{d(A^Tx)}{dA} = ? $, where $ A \in R^{n \times m}$ and $x \in R^n$.

Answer (score 2):

Let function $\mathrm f : \mathbb R^{m \times n} \to \mathbb R^n$ be defined by

$$\mathrm f (\mathrm X) := \mathrm X^\top \mathrm a$$

where $\mathrm a \in \mathbb R^m$ is given. The $i$-th entry of $\mathrm f$ is the $\mathbb R^{m \times n} \to \mathbb R$ function

$$f_i (\mathrm X) = \mathrm e_i^\top \mathrm X^\top \mathrm a = \mathrm a^\top \mathrm X \,\mathrm e_i = \mbox{tr} (\mathrm e_i \mathrm a^\top \mathrm X) = \mbox{tr} ((\mathrm a \mathrm e_i^\top)^\top \mathrm X) = \langle \mathrm a \mathrm e_i^\top, \mathrm X \rangle$$

Hence, the derivative of function $f_i$ with respect to $\mathrm X$ is the $m \times n$ matrix

$$\partial_{\mathrm X} f_i (\mathrm X) = \mathrm a \mathrm e_i^\top$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f:A\rightarrow A^Tx$ is linear. Then the derivative is $Df_A:H\in M_{n,m}\rightarrow H^Tx\in\mathbb{R}^m$.

In other words, if $(e_i)$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^m$, then  $\dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{a_{i,j}}}=x_ie_j$